# How does a long name effect the response size?

Tags: java, playframework

I am using play framework for web development. I was wondering what is the effect of the longer variable on user's query processing.In other words how the name of the variable affects the query size? Does a longer name means longer query to be sent and thus longer time for a user request to process? Does a shorter JSON means shorter response time to user? Shorter variable names will significantly reduce the readability of the code.

### What I have found

If I rename my variable to be send in a json from autoEngineId to aeId there is not much performance gain but thats maybe because I dont have significant amount of user requests to process. The site is in dev mode.

Can somebody please tell me what is the advantage/disadvantage of smaller varibale names in JSON?

Comment: Marginally less bandwidth used? More difficult for third party developers to understand messages? I'll let you decide if that last is an advantage or disadvantage on your own. =)

Comment: Disadvantage of shorter names (if shortened aggressively): Reduced readability. Less self-documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your variable names are the length of college essays, there's not going to be a noticeable difference in response times over the network. Spend your time optimizing where it counts. That will be where profiling tells you it will count.

The primary advantage of shorter names is less typing for the programmer. Make the names long enough so that when you come back to your code after a month, the name will provide at least a clue as to what it's being used for. Because you will have forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you profile your application to determine where you can improve performance.  Even after 20 years experience of tuning performance systems I still find that measuring is the only way to be sure you are a) working on the most significant performance improvements b) you don't make matters worse.

In your case, I assume you have particular reason to believe the length of attribute names is a performance issue, it just something you change. This approach to performance tuning is more likely to make matter worse than better.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller variable names may save you a little bandwidth, but the performance impact (unless you have hundreds of thousands of entries an object array), is going to be so small, you are unlikely to notice anything.

The impact of not having meaning variable names will cost you far more in the long run. Performance and Scalability are cheap, man-power is not, and well designed code will always pay for itself many times over in the long term.